# J2ME RMS Read/Write 

Tags: java-me, rms

I am creating a J2ME application.in which i have created a record an have to access it frequently every time updating its value.But every time i run my application it creates the record again an again as i have written the creation code of record in startApp().I couldn't get where to define the creation code so dat next time i access record  i should get updated value ?
the updation thing is defined in `Commandlistener`.

Comment: Any updates with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Write a method which creates the record and another one which reads from the record store.  Call the method that creates the record only if no record exists.